# What Serialization format is used in Bitcoin?

Tags: serialization

What serialization format is used in bitcoin network? I know in Ethereum, there is the  RLP which has been replaced with SSZ. Polkadot has it's own serialization format called SCALE, but I have not been able to find information on what serialization format is used in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin uses different serialization formats for different data structures, as described on https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation.

See also [In what format does a block store the transaction data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/113631/in-what-format-does-a-block-store-the-transaction-data) for a similar question.

Comment: > Bitcoin uses different serialization formats for different data structures. I see. I am mostly asking for the network serialisation format. Which format is used for this?

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided? It describes the Bitcoin network protocol, including the serialization for P2P messages.

Comment: Normally link-only answers are not preferred (they can become broken, out of date, etc), but in this case its perhaps more tenable, considering how general the question is (and thus how much info would be included in a complete answer-- eg basically copy/pasting the entire contents of the first link)