# Can we have more than one address in transaction inputs and outputs addresses attribute?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, raw-data

In the transaction data of bitcoin can we have more than one address element in adresses attribute of inputs and outputs of a transaction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what blockchain explorers might show you, The network format for Bitcoin transactions contains no addresses.

Transactions can have multiple inputs and multiple outputs. Each output has a locking script. An address is a convenient abstraction of a script. Thus a transaction can have at least two and sometimes thousands of associated addresses.

Each input and each output for common types of transaction are only associated with one address.

A multi-signature transaction can be more complex. This might be what you are thinking of.

---

Related

- [In what format does a block store the transaction data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113631/13866)